# Are foreign keys sequential in Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Suppose I have two tables - `Order` and `OrderDetails`, which are joined this way:

```
SELECT Order.Name, OrderDetails.OrderId, OrderDetails.Quantity
FROM Order
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Order.Id = OrderDetails.OrderId
```

As far as I know, rows might be joined in any order, but are distinct `OrderId` values guaranteed to be returned sequentially?
Task description:

> Receive a recordset from server and process it in a loop, creating a new `Order` object in code for each new `OrderId`.

Comment: There is *one* way to guarantee the order of rows returned by a query. That is by specifying an `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost query. That's it. Just state your requirements there. Don't search for "hidden" ordering guarantees, they do not exist.

Comment: **ALL** queries are only ordered by what you put in your `ORDER BY` clause. Without an `ORDER BY` clause the rows are returned in a non-deterministic order. You task doesn't specify what order they need to be in anyway?

Comment: The task description in your question does not require ordering of results. The Order objects can be created in any order so the order of the result set does not matter.

Comment: I am using pagination and ordering is done separately on a field which is not `OrderID`. But I added it as a second ordering field and now I can process my recordset sequentially. I was hoping it's already done by SQL engine so I don't need to add extra overhead.

Comment: @JaneksBergs - what "overhead" do you think you're adding? SQL is a *declarative* language. You describe *what result set you want*, and it's the job of the query optimizer to work out how best to achieve that result. Adding the `ORDER BY` clause may result in *no change* in how the query is processed - but now the engine is aware that you want results in a particular order and will now *guarantee* to produce results in that order.